# git updating from master repository with changes pending in my local copy

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and still trying to get my head around using it. I cloned a master repository onto my local system and started working on a project(made some changes/ added new files). Meanwhile, the master repository is updated with changes from other contributors and now i am unable to pull those changes since my copy is a few commits ahead of the master already. How do i solve this issue?

EDIT1:
I used the command `git pull master` and get the following error message

"You asked to pull from the remote 'master', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line."

Comment: What does it mean that you cannot pull the changes? Any error message appears?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Kindly provide details of how you have tried to solve the problem. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What error is shown?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion make a [branch](https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches) and then go with that, if master get updated you can easily pull that to your master and then insert it to your branch by commit them into your branch

Comment: Why is it so complicated. Isn't it supposed to be a basic feature for git? I mean collaboration is why we use git isn't it?

Comment: haha true, when I started git it was a nightmare to learn it but you get use to it really fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

to update your local master branch, and it will replay your commits on top of remote's master. As others have said though, it is best to work on a feature branch which is code reviewed and merged in later on.

The error you have pasted in your question actually says that git doesn't know which branch to merge it to. You can specify that with

```
git branch --set-upstream master remote/master
```

This would normally be specified with `--track` or inside git config files.